# What training is required for pilots conducting ASETPA operations?

Tags: casa-regulations, australia

In Australia, aircraft approved for ASETPA operations are certain single-engine turbines allowed to be operated commercially under IFR. While I understand that the manufacturer is required to meet a series of requirement, I'm not so sure about whether the pilots in ASETPA operations need special training or approval. Is extra training and/or testing required, and if so, how extensive is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [CASA AOC Handbook](http://www.casa.gov.au/wcmswr/_assets/main/manuals/regulate/aocm/220r015_Vol2.pdf), section 15.3.1.2, pilots do need to have specific training. Most of this training is regarding engine failures and emergency landings, in some situations in IMC.

> CASA requires that all ASETPA operators have a training and checking
> organisation.
>
> The CASA Inspector will verify that for ASETPA
> operator’s the following additional procedures are included within the
> training and checking organisation:
>
> - Engine failure or malfunction which necessitates stopping the aircraft on the ground
> - Engine failure or malfunction which necessitates an off-airport landing after take- off on the most suitable terrain in the vicinity of the aerodrome. These can be organised into a number of procedures, depending on the height of the aircraft at the time of the failure
> - Engine failure or malfunction which necessitates turning to execute a glide landing upon a serviceable runway, including a ‘turn-back’ manoeuvre. This procedure is to contain a minimum indicated airspeeds and altitudes
> - Engine malfunction, during climb, cruise and descent and from the approach to land phase in VMC and IMC
> - Additional procedures for the conduct of a forced landing in IMC to ground level

The next section discusses route limitations, which I am assuming the pilots should at least be familiar with.